# 404 error on Google Webmaster toools

Tags: http-status-code-404, google-search-console

I have some issues with 404´s on google web master tools.

Google is telling us this one is a 404 (is a real 404): 
http://www.apartmentratings.com/VA-Midlothian-Woodlake-Village-Waterpoint.html

And that url is linked from: 
http://www.apartmentratings.com/rate/VA-Midlothian-Crowne-at-Swift-Creek-Map.html

But that url, is not there, is not on the code, nothing.

I don´t know why google is saying we have a 404 there. I had to create some apache rules to avoid this, rewriting those urls with the "/rate" prefix.

Answer (score 0):

click on "**Mark as Fixed**" under  **Crawl > Crawl Errors** and see if it helps